# Converting a python3.6 application that uses PyQt5, pymysql and selenium to exe

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm working to an apllication that uses selenium for scraping a webpage and stores the data in a mysql database. I'm using mysql server 8.0 and i want to be able to use this application in a mac computer.
Is there a way to do that? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Python and MySQL server on your Mac using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). From here you can install your necessary Python dependencies via `pip` and run your application.

Alternatively, you could setup the application as a [Docker service](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/) with [containers](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) for each component. This is probably the easiest way, though you'll need to navigate the docker learning curve.